# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

This is my backend code in Node

```
import express from 'express';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const app = express();


app.get("/getData", (req, res) => {
    let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
    fetch(url)
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(json => {
            res = res.json(json);
        })
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

Running this independantly is giving me the desired output - Which is an array List of objects

Now, this is my frontend code in react .

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/getData")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => setData(data.message));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <p>{!data ? "Loading..." : data}</p>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Running this is giving me the above mentioned exception in the console during inspection and no UI output is coming.

This is my package.json file

```
{
    "name": "node-react-project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "node server/index.js"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.18.1",
        "node-fetch": "^3.2.10"
    },
    "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
    "type": "module"
}
```

This is the response I am getting when logging the response from the fetch without the conversion to JSON.

[https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipMZXrNK-8MdosXzUXlqQvpwtlYhe6xCmmJ70xIc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud1u9.png)

Comment: First of all I think while doing the fetch in react you have to put the complete url not just the endpoint

Comment: Put a .catch after the second then and then I think you can see the complete error

Comment: @HarshGupta I tried putting the complete url, and got a similar issue. Provided that by complete url you mean "http://localhost:3000/getData" and not the file location.

Comment: @HarshGupta and I think I understand the error as being the res.json() is trying to parse an HTML page to JSON format, but how I am getting an HTML page as response from the api where I am clearly returning a JSON response is beyond me.

Comment: in your then remove all json conversions and just log the response and see what exactly are you getting

Comment: @HarshGupta
Am getting a Response object with all sets of values like statusText: "OK" and status: 200 with a lot of nested objects. How can I show you the logged value?

Comment: add the screenshot in your question

Comment: I dont think your backend is returning a json object, I dont know how to fix it, but I think that is where the problem lies

Comment: Not really a problem but you shouldn't have `res =` in `res = res.json(json)`

Comment: Looks like you put the `proxy` config into your server's `package.json`. It should be in your React app's `package.json`. This can be closed as a **typo**