# How to fix SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Tags: node.js, react-native, fetch

So I'm new to React Native and I'm trying to send data from my app to my backend and siplay that data on my backend console.

Problem : I keep on getting this error :

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON.

Looked a little everywhere about how to fix this issue, nothing worked...

Here's what the part that's sending data from my frontend look like :

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => {

fetch(API_URL+'/get', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
},
body:JSON.stringify({
  'name': 'item name',
  'description': 'item description',
})
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
  console.log(responseJson);
  this.setState({
      data: responseJson
   })
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
})}

  } style={styles.Button}>
    <Text style={styles.ButtonText}>3abez</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
```

I'm expecting to see on my console :
{'name' : 'item name'}

Comment: There is likely an erorr on the API side, and that means the API is returning a HTML error page instead of the actual data. To see the error, find the request in the developer tools network pane, select it, click on the preview tab and observe the contents.

Comment: Thought it might be interesting to you that I just received this from Dropbox while trying to log in.

Answer (score 4):

**It seems like the server is returning HTML instead of JSON. This is why you're getting the "Unexpected token '<'" error, because the HTML is not valid JSON.**

- To fix this issue, you need to check what the server is sending back
  and make sure it's returning a JSON object. If the server is not set
  up correctly, you'll need to correct that.
- Additionally, make sure that the API endpoint you're sending the
  request to is correct and it's the endpoint that is set up to receive
  and handle POST requests.
- You can also check the response headers and status code of the
  server's response to see if there's any error being returned.

---

***Here's a working code example for sending data from your React Native app to a backend and display the response data in the console:***

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';

const API_URL = 'http://your-backend-endpoint.com';

class App extends Componenenter code heret {
  constructor(props) {`enter code here`
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {},
    };
  }

  handlePress = () => {
    fetch(API_URL + '/get', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: 'item name',
        description: 'item description',
      }),
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        console.log(responseJson);
        this.setState({
          data: responseJson,
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePress} style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Send Data</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'black',
  },
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by deleting proxy: "url" from my package json.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is at Api side. the api returning HTML/nothing or its is not hitting the endpoint.
log the response so you can see what is wrong.[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73392812/uncaught-in-promise-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-doctype-is-not)